# str.match() Python Match Either of the values

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a dataframe df, and Column as column1
By using str.match how can i check whether the Column value is in either of the values ('Value1','Value2')

It can be Done like this

```
(df['column1'].str.lower().str.match(Value1')) | (df['column1'].str.lower().str.match('Value2'))
```

or like this By using lambda function:

```
df[column1].apply(lambda x : True if x in ['Value1','Value2'] else False)
```

Looking for anything like

```
   (df['column1'].str.lower().str.match('Value1' | 'Value1' ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin` method if you are looking for exact match:

```
df[column1].isin(['Value1', 'Value2'])
```

Or if using `str.match`, use `|` as or logic in the regex pattern:

```
df[column1].str.lower().str.match("Value1|Value2")
```

Comment: Yes, This is what i wanted.